# Excel - How to look up data in a pivot table and use the values in the next cell?

Tags: excel, pivot, lookup

I have a Pivot table like this

[image: Pivot Table]

I try to convert this to a user table with all names and have the data listed by day

[image]

I tried to use VLookup bus not being succesfull in separating the code in a column structure.

Apologies for the pictures I tried to add a table structure but it didn't work out.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to isolate regions based on the date you provide, then vlookup on that area, here is the formula, you can try:

```
C18==IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B18,INDEX($B$3:$B$15,MATCH(C$17,$B$3:$B$15,0)):INDEX($C$3:$C$15,IFERROR(MATCH(D$17,$B$3:$B$15,0),13)),2,0),"")
```

[image]

Comment: It partially works, if the last date value is checked the figures don't show up so where your 11/12/13 show I don't see a value they all error out. I noticed that you pin the last value_if_error is set to $C12 I might do something wrong copying the formula through the other cells as that value goes up to outside the C3:C15 range?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the date range is 31 day so if I try to work that one in the formula becomes slightly unmanageble

Comment: I didn't notice C12, it was 13. In addition, it is not necessary to be 13, you just need to get max (row (scope))=15 then minus min(row(scope)) =3 then +1 =13. I think this is the simplest formula. If you want more complex formulas. Perhaps wait for someone to answer